# Given $\left | _A \mathbf r _B \right | = \left | _C \mathbf r _B \right | = 10$, prove that $0 \le \left | _A \mathbf r _C \right | \le 20$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

The question:

> If $\left | _A \mathbf r _B \right | = \left | _C \mathbf r _B \right | = 10$, prove that $0 \le \left | _A \mathbf r _C \right | \le 20$.

Note that

> $_A \mathbf r _B:$ the position of $A$ relative to $B$, which is $\overline{OA}-\overline{OB}$.
>
> $\left | \mathbf r \right |$: magnitude of vector $\mathbf r$.

I was able to complete the question, but using a diagram and some logic. My attempt:
[image]

$\left | _A \mathbf r _C \right |$ is at a minimum when $A=C \implies \left | _A \mathbf r _C \right |=0$. Maximum is when $B$ is on $_A \mathbf r _C \implies \left | _A \mathbf r _C \right | = 10+10 =20$. Hence $0 \le \left | _A \mathbf r _C \right | \le 20$.

Is there any way to do this question with pure algebra? I suppose the triangle inequality will appear somewhere but I have no idea how to link the information the question gives you with an inequality.

Comment: What exactly is $\mathbf r$? I am sadly unfamiliar with this kind of writing.

Comment: @mike239x I will edit my question to address all notational issues. To answer your question, $\mathbf r$ is just a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done purely algebraically. It is an instance of the *triangle inequality*, which can be derived from the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), which itself has a purely algebraic proof. The proof of Cauchy–Schwarz and the derivation of the triangle inequality are both on the linked Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

Well here you go:
$$_C \mathbf r _B =  -1\cdot  _B \mathbf r _C 
\Rightarrow 
\lvert _C \mathbf r _B\rvert = \lvert -1\rvert \cdot \lvert _B \mathbf r _C\rvert= \lvert _B \mathbf r _C\rvert$$
and due to triangle inequality you have:
$$\lvert _A \mathbf r _C\rvert \leq \lvert _A \mathbf r _B\rvert + \lvert _B \mathbf r _C\rvert = \lvert _A \mathbf r _B\rvert + \lvert _C \mathbf r _B\rvert  = 10+10 = 20$$